# Resource not found exception in 1.5 version

Tags: android, xml

```
10-28 11:24:10.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.build/com.example.build.ComBuild}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_large.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_large.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1625)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:535)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at com.example.build.ComBuild.onCreate(ComBuild.java:15)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     ... 11 more
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: invalid drawable tag animated-rotate
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:745)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:695)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1622)
10-28 11:24:10.610: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748):     ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's an error in your `progress_large.xml` file.  The key line in the log is this one:

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: invalid drawable tag animated-rotate
```

My guess is that `<animated-rotate>` isn't available in 1.5 if your app is working on later versions.